# Why is the javascript tag code not changing colors and staying white/greyed out?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using spring boot, thymeleaf, and MySQL and I want to use the datatables library to format the data in an HTML table. I want to use an internal javascript tag to type the jQuery code which is supposed to specify the table options:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
} );
```

This is my thymeleaf template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
  <title>User List</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/static/datatables.js}"></script>
  <!--    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/datatables.js"></script>-->
</head>

<body>
  <h1>User List</h1>
  <table id="reps" class="display" data-order='[[1, "asc"]]' data-page-length="25">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Company</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr th:each="rep : ${reps}">
        <td th:text="${rep.firstName}"></td>
        <td th:text="${rep.lastName}"></td>
        <td th:text="${rep.email}"></td>
        <td th:text="${rep.gender}"></td>
        <td th:text="${rep.company}"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!--<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#reps').DataTable();
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

When the webpage is loaded, it presents a blank white background, however, the console has the following errors:

```
1) Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
2) jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).DataTable is not a function TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/rep/users:726:20)
    at e (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js:2:30310)
    at t (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js:2:30612) undefined
3) Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (users:726:20)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2:30310)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2:30612)
```

**Update**
Ok I still didn't get the internal JS to work but it works now with the external JavaScript file because my location path was incorrect. This is the corrected version: `<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{../static/datatables.js}"></script>`

Comment: What is `$('#reps')`? Does it contain an object you expect and does it have a `DataTable` key?

Comment: #reps is the <table> Id

Comment: Yes, I am aware of how jQuery works, however, what is the object returned there? It's clearly not having issues with step 1 (`$(document)`) so I'm thinking the `$('#reps')` is not containing what you think it does. Have you logged that before doing the `DataTable` call on the key?

Comment: is it because you import that data tables script in the header before you import the cdn data tables script?  Also, what letting us know what resource it failed to load would be helpful (check your network tab, one of the urls should be in red with a 404 next to it)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question much But the table is supposed to be pulling data from the MySQL database, which it does and is shown on the webpage, until I place the jQuery code in the script tag then it causes the errors/

Comment: `the server responded with a status of 404` - looks like you've got the wrong path to your local copy of datatables.js - but you do load it later.  Try to remove the errors that don't need to be there...

Comment: Seems the data tables part of it works ok - I turned your code into a runnable snippet and it creates a data table

Comment: If your table was rendered before that script was ran, there should be no issue. But it's clear it's ran after now, as your screen remains blank. That means that piece of code is running before your table has been populated, and an error thrown so it never gets populated at all. Maybe try adding a `defer` to your script tag?

Comment: Change `$(document).ready(function() {` to `console.log($.fn.jquery);$(document).ready(function() { console.log($.fn.jquery);` and report back with the two values.   This can happen if there's *another* jquery loaded *after* your script, eg in a framework that adds its own jquery.

Comment: Update: the path to the external JS file was incorrect, this is the corrected version: `<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{../static/datatables.js}"></script>`

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Glad you got it sorted.